# How do you update locally cached data in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the cloud_firestore Dart package for my Flutter application. From my understanding, there is no expiration time on data cached from Firestore queries. So if for example, user A updates their public profile and user B already has user A's profile cached locally, does user B ever see the new profile data?

This question came up because I made changes to the database directly through the firebase console, and I can't get the new data to show in my application (I assume I need to clear the local cache).

Comment: The cache is updated automatically whenever you read new data from the server. It's more likely we can help is you edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that anyone of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).\

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm sorry I'm not sure how to make a standalone example since it depends on a firestore database. I'm unfamiliar with SO procedures - should I just delete the post?